# Cannot pass module functions to Page

Tags: phantomjs

I have a module called `util` with the methods `getMutedColor` and some others. `getMutedColor` relies on another called `rand` in the same module.

```
page.includeJs('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js', function() {
    var util = require('./util');
    var svg = page.evaluate(pageContext.pageExec, data, meta, util);
    /** ... **/
}
```

I can call `util.getMutedColor()` just fine within this scope but in my `pageContext.pageExec` function, `util.getMutedColor` no longer exists. The `util` parameter is still an object, but I cannot call *any* of the exported methods:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'util.getMutedColor()')

Is there a way to pass a self-contained module to a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not really possible. As seen in the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.

The function that you pass to evaluate must be self-contained and the data that you pass cannot contain functions or objects that are created with `new`. Those are stripped.

This means that you must copy the `util` object completely into the `pageExec` function.

If `util` is too big to copy or if you use multiple functions of `util`, you can try **different** things:

1. Serialize the functions and pass them as strings to the evaluate callback where you would instantiate them with `new Function(string)` and bind them to the `util` object.

   ```js
   var funcNames = [];
   for(var prop in util) {
       if (util.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof util[prop] === "function") {
           funcNames.push(prop);
           util[prop] = util[prop].toString();
       }
   }
   util.__funcNames = funcNames; // make it a property of util
   page.evaluate(pageContext.pageExec, data, meta, util);
   ```

   and inside of `pageContext.pageExec`:

   ```js
   util.__funcNames.forEach(function(funcName){
       util[funcName] = new Function(util[funcName]);
   });
   ```
2. Have only a single `pageContext` function which contains everything and you can use a `switch case` with a parameter that is passed every time to `evaluate` to select the proper function inside of the single `pageContext` function.
3. Use [`page.injectJs`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) to inject the utils. It would be necessary to namespace the utils in by checking if `window` is present with something like that:

   ```js
   var util = {...};
   if (window) {
       window.util = util
   } else if(module) {
       module.exports = util;
   }
   ```

   Probably there are better scripts out there to do this depending on the environment.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you for referencing the docs and providing clear examples.